# SQL error #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I want to import database, I get the next error:

```
Error

SQL query:

--
-- Dumping data for table wp_comments
--
INSERT INTO wp_comments ( comment_ID , comment_post_ID , comment_author , comment_author_email , comment_author_url , comment_author_IP , comment_date , comment_date_gmt , comment_content , comment_karma , comment_approved , comment_agent , comment_type , comment_parent , user_id )
VALUES ( 1, 1, 'Sr WordPress', '', 'https://wordpress.org/', '', '2016-03-05 18:59:12', '2016-03-06 00:59:12', 'Hola, esto es un comentario.\nPara borrar un comentario simplemente accede y revisa los comentarios de la entrada. Ahí tendrás la opción de editarlo o borrarlo.', 0, 'post-trashed', '', '', 0, 0 ) ;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: If you want to fully import WP database empty your database/tables first.

Answer (score 3):

Your `wp_comments` table already has a comment with id "1".

You will need to remove the existing entries.

If you want to keep them, then remove the "id" field from all comments you're importing.